# Difference between Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

Are Chrome and Edge both built on Chromium? If so, why are both web browsers needed and what are the differences?

Comment: [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)): “Google uses the code to make its Chrome browser, which has more features than Chromium. Many other browsers are also based on Chromium code, most notably Microsoft Edge and Opera. In addition, some parties (although not Google) build the code as-is and release browsers with the Chromium name.” That means that Chromium is the bare-minimum core browser. Others can add whatever they want on top of it. Such as higher integrations with other systems such as Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two browsers are two adaptations of the open-source
[Chromium Project](https://www.chromium.org/).

Chrome is from Google and Edge is by Microsoft.

As regarding features and performance, there are small differences only.
Microsoft Edge has a wee bit better performance on Windows, naturally,
and has omitted all the methods that Google uses to track Chrome users.

It is your decision as to which one to use.

A detailed comparison is found in the article
[Google Chrome Vs. Microsoft Edge: What to Choose in 2021?](https://browserhow.com/chrome-vs-edge/)

Comment: Chromium is just the minimal browser core. Others take that core, tweak and adapt it for specific needs that they care about: Such as OS specific needs and such. Chrome and Opera and Edge are all based on Chromium but all have different core advantages.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Read the linked article, and you'll see that the adaptations are small compared to the core features. I didn't find the comparison to give a conclusive win to either of them.